# How reliable is page write-tracking in Windows given processor caches

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Does [`::GetWriteWatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-getwritewatch) always give an up to date list of modified pages? Or is it possible, because of processor caches, that some pages are still considered unmodified because cached writes have not been flushed to main memory?

---

Consider the following snippet of C++ code:

```
auto ptr = ::VirtualAlloc(NULL, 8192, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, MEM_WRITE_WATCH);
auto num = new (ptr) int{};
::ResetWriteWatch(ptr, 8192);

// ... calculations that involve writing to 'num' ...

::GetWriteWatch(/* ... */);
```

This should reserve and commit two pages of virtual memory, modify the first page, and finally request all modified pages.

Is it guaranteed that the first page is listed as modified by the call to `::GetWriteWatch`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's no coincidence that a write watch operates at page granularity. That's because this handled at CPU level, via the Page Table for the MMU. I can't find an authoritative source,  but I understand that this works via the read-only page attribute. A watched page is read-only, but the soft page fault when writing is handled by adding the watched page to the modified list.

As such, stale data in processor caches are irrelevant. This is handled at MMU level, and the MMU is closely coupled to caches anyway.

I'd be more worried about race conditions, because those appear at C++ level. A write to the watched page could happen from another thread even as `GetWriteWatch` is running.

Comment: In my example snippet, would the call to `ResetWriteWatch` then ensure that a subsequent write access to `num` causes a page fault? Or is it possible that `num` is manipulated entirely in CPU registers and is only flushed to main memory after the call the `GetWriteWatch`?

Comment: @MaartenBamelis `ResetWriteWatch` would mark all the pages in the region as read only.  Any write into that area would trigger the soft page fault (before any memory content was written), and Windows would note that the page was written to.

Comment: @MaartenBamelis: _On a single thread_, the compiler doesn't know how `num` and `GetWriteWatch` interact, so it must flush all variables to memory.

Comment: @MSalters I see. So, it basically all works fine because `GetWriteWatch` is a function call and therefore `num` is flushed to memory. But it's not a special property of `GetWriteWatch` because any other function call would also flush `num` to memory.

Comment: @MaartenBamelis: Specifically, it's a call to an external (OS) function. An optimizing compiler might discover it's unnecessary to flush `num` when calling another function in the same program.

Answer (score 8):

The blunt answer is *assumed* **Yes** .

While the documentation doesn't give an *explicit* guarentee, it can be assumed since it is dealing with MMU and CPU and low level memory management. This works as the rest of API: see [creating guard pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Memory/creating-guard-pages) etc. Taken together, all these guard and protect features of the API wouldn't be half as usefull as they actual are if you couldn't count on them being precise down to the instruction causing the fault. That being said, how this is actually accomplished by OS/CPU/MMU/TLB/CACHE is somewhat in the dark to me- will update if I figure it out.

In your example, I would be more worried about the compiler/optimizer playing some trick on you- so perhaps take a look at the generated assembly and see where the actual write is.